# Assign specific content of a .txt file into a bash variable

Tags: bash, variables, text, terminal

I have a txt file and i want to assign a specific word from inside the text file and its many lines. e.g Let's say that the text file is this sentence and the value 0.78 is the one that i want to get assigned. How do i do that?

Comment: it's is difficult to understand what you want to do from what you're saying. please elaborate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you are looking for a number, so I'll extract anything that looks like a number:

```
grep -Ewo "[+-]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+" file
echo $n

0.78
```

The regex says it can have an optional +/- at the start, some optional digits, an optional decimal point and some more digits.

If you only want the number with a decimal point in it, and you want that in a `bash` variable, do this

```
var=$(grep -Ewo "[+-]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]*" file)
echo $var
```

Comment: i tried the command and the return is pretty much expected but let me be more specific: in the txt file there are 2 numbers, one that is the patient ID and it's like 100454 and the number that i want which is always something like (-)0.35 .It always has a dot. With the above command both of the numbers are returned but i only want the second one and also i want it to be stored in a bash variable. If i do something like var=the_correct_command can i get the number as a bash variable?

Comment: Have another look now please.

Comment: that works but still the var contains the two numbers. I want to keep only the second one.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your context is, but let's assume you want to match the number immediately following the word "value" in your text file, and you want to do it in pure Bash:

```
$ [[ $(<yourfile.txt) =~ value\ ([0-9.]*) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
0.78
```

See [Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs) in the Bash manual for more information.